# Fastest way to retrieve user input in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was wondering what is the best ( fatest (and?) safest way to retrieve user input in meteor.
It is Javascript, I know that there is jQuery so I came with two solutions personaly :

FIRST ONE :

In the HTML, with only the input :

```
<input id='input1' type='text' />
```

that I retrieve with :

```
Template{(
    'event #input1' : function(){ 
        // event like change or keyup
        var data = $('#input1').val()...
        ...
```

etc... or SECOND :

In the HTML, with only the input :

```
<form>
    <input name='input1' id='input1' type='text' />
</form>
```

that I retrieve with :

```
Template{(
    'submit form' : function(e){
        e.prenventDefault(); //avoid page refresh
        var data = $(e.target).find('[name=input1]').val()...
        //Is this faster because it only search the data in the form and not in the whole page ?
        ...
```

So what do you use ? And why ? Is the form element still usefull ? Only for handling several inputs, safer, faster ?

Comment: In first option I would rather recommend $(e.currentTarget).val(), and I think it's the fastest way but not sure so I'll jsut leave the comment

Comment: With the submit event on the form, you can directly get the value like this: `e.target.input1.value`.
No jQuery involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the second option. In the first option, you're getting the data as soon as it's available (keyup, change, etc.) to store.... where? If you want to implement a WIP (Work In Progress) form, I highly recommend to use the first approach and save it to local storage. Don't insert it right away in the database.

It makes much more sense that when the user provided the input, the user confirms that he's done editing the data and presses saves. This way you save to the database once. On the first approach if you save to the database every single time the data changes, other clients subscribing to the data will get lots of updates and will notice that something weird is happening. It really depends on what you want to done.

Even if you want to save the data right away, consider the idea o saving to localStorage, set a timeout to send the data to the database and also try to make sure that you don't have clients watch that dataset.

Comment: Thanks ! but in fact i'm also using if(e.keyCode == 13)(enter key) to avoid this problem, as you said, to store every change. But still it runs the code (if(e.keyCode) == 13) a lot of times but it's on the client so i'm ok with that. I was questionning the perf differences between the form way and the jQuery way. But as user3557327 said I can use the event way with e.target.value ! (even without tje form element). So I think it's the best way and the fastest. I'll put it as the answer if there no other option in some days.

Comment: You can use the event 'change'. "if(e.keyCode) == 13" is minor operation. Also I think that we're discussing something that isn't a performance issue at all. I found that you're saving every keypress in realtime but if not: It's just a matter of taste and coding style. You should worry that much about little things like these.